# scope values inside the google map event listener not getting in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

scope values inside the  this function not updating the view.
I tried adding   `$scope.$apply();`  just below the all the scope values please help me. the values of  `$rootScope` able to get in view not the `$scope` values.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, $scope, $rootScope) {
    return function() {

        if ($rootScope.showMobile) {
            $scope.cityDetail();
            $scope.placehoderInfo = false;
            $scope.pencilfirst = marker.information + '' + ',' + marker.state + '-' + marker.pin_zip;
            $scope.name_of_business = marker.name_of_business;
            $scope.$apply();
        } else {

            $rootScope.showDetails = false;
            $scope.pencilsecond = marker.information + '' + ',' + marker.state + '-' + marker.pin_zip;
            $rootScope.showwithOutMob = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
})(marker, $scope, $rootScope));
```

The HTML code

```
<div   ng-show="showDetails">
   <h4 class="text_display">{{pencilfirst}}</h4>
</div>

<div   ng-show="showwithOutMob">
   <h4 class="text_display">{{pencilsecond}}</h4>
</div>
```

On marker click I am displaying this information right side of the map. left side I am showing the map, on right side information about marker I am displaying.